# Ошибка при добавлении пункта в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Когда я пытаюсь добавить пункт в `RecyclerView` вот так (внешне это вызывается в цикле из `AsyncTask`):

```
//mListFormOne — лист, который передается в адаптер
//mAdapter — адаптер, подключенный к RecyclerView
//record — новая запись для добавления в RecyclerView

mListFormOne.add(record);
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mListFormOne.size() - 1);
```

Раз через раз выбивает ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2042)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:4129)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:9302)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyItemInserted(RecyclerView.java:5662)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.fragments.PageWords.addRecordFormOne(PageWords.java:60)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity$LoadData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:289)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity$LoadData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:207)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Как это исправить?

---

UPD_0:
Юрий,

```
mListFormTwo.add(record);

Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

handler.post(r);
```

Ошибка:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.adapters.RecyclerWordsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.fragments.PageWords.addRecordFormOne(PageWords.java:58)
        at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity$LoadData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:289)
        at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity$LoadData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:207)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644466/3212712) сие лечится обновлением адаптера с помощью `Handler`:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mListFormOne.size() - 1);
    }
};

handler.post(r);
```

Ещё на en-SO пытаются это объяснить на англо-саксонсом и предлагают ещё одно [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069171/3212712).

Comment: Ну...... Почти. Обновил вопрос :).

Comment: @bukashka101, у вас адаптер нулл.

Comment: Теперь новая ошибка... Надеюсь, это уже та истина, которую я так долго ждал. Последние три фрагмента (практически одинаковых) и Java код приложения будет закончен :D!

Comment: Добавьте в ответ, что `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mListFormOne.size() - 1);` нужно использовать, когда нужно вставить вместо уже имеющегося пункта, а `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, если вообще ничего нет.